# Pass nodejs function to page.$$eval in pupeteer

Tags: jquery, node.js, puppeteer

How do I pass a function to Puppeteer page.$$eval function? I have the below code but does not work.

```
     await page.exposeFunction("mapDateValue", (value) => {
      return mapDateValue(value);
    });
  const receiptData = await page.$$eval(
      ".section-expandable-content",
      (result, values) => {
         // call mapdateValueFunction but is undefined
          result.map(async (pageData, i) => {

          return mapDateValue(pageData.querySelector('.test-class'))
        });
       });
        return valuesMap;
      }
    );
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.mapDateValue(...)`?

Comment: @Molda I can't access window object within nodejs.

Comment: Why? Have you tried it? According to the docs the function you pass to the `$$eval` function is evaluated within a browser context where the window should be accessible.